# upload file api with uploadtask in symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8, nsurlsessionuploadtask

We realize that if we want to produce a multipart query that contains a video file of 15GB, it is impossible to allocate in memory the size needed for such a large amount of data, most devices have only 2 or 3GB of RAM.

It is therefore absolutely necessary to switch to the uploadTask method which will push to the server the contents of a block file of the maximum size allowed by the IP packets sent to the server.

This is a POST method. However, it does not contain parameters such as the folder id or the file name. So you need a way to transmit these parameters. The best way is to code them in the URL.

I proposed an encoding format in the form of a path behind the endpoint of the API, but we can also very well encode these two parameters in a classic way in the URL, eg:

```
/api/upload?id=123&filename=video.mp4
```

From what I read on Stackoverflow, it's trivial with Symfony to retrieve id and filename. Then all the data received in the body of the POST request can be written in a raw way directly into a file, without also passing through a buffer in server-side memory.

The user data must imperatively be streamed, whether mobile side or server side, and whether upload or download. Loading user content in memory is also very dangerous in terms of security.

In symfony, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This goes way beyond Symfony and depends on the web server you are using.

By default with apache/nginx and php you will receive an already buffered request, so you cannot stream it to a file.

However, there are solutions, for example with Apache you can stream requests, see http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html#Request_Response_entity_streaming

Probably nginx also has options for it, but I don't know about those.

Another option might be websockets, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket